# Fedora 18 safe remove usb drive

Tags: fedora, usb-drive, unmounting, eject

How can I safe remove a usb drive from the Gnome 3.6.2 GUI? This feature used to be available in the past (up to 16, I haven't used 17) from the Desktop and Computer tab in nautilus.

The eject arrow and the unmount features do not power down the device. So, is there a way to do this "old" safe remove?

Comment: Are you sure that this actually matters?  I think it is the same difference between, eg, pulling a plug out of a wall, and flipping a breaker to cut power to the plug.  From a device perspective, it is the exact same event anyway.  You can "spin the drive down" by unplugging it, or by cutting the power.  6 == 2*3

Comment: @goldilocks I do think it is safer to cut the power off before unplugging the device.

Comment: I understand that you *think* that is true, I was just wondering if you had any particular reason for thinking that, beyond superstition.  No offence ;)

Comment: @goldilocks I wouldn't call it "superstition" I'd call it assurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this feature has been removed from `Gnome`, and neither `nautilus` nor `nemo` file browsers have it.

So I wrote this small script and added a new `udev` rule to allow me to safe remove my usb drives.

`udev` rule:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/91-usb_device_rule.rules 
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?[1-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/home/user/usb_script '%k'"
```

`usb_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEV="/dev/$1"
DEVR="/dev/${1:0:3}"

for DISKLABEL in `find /dev/disk/by-label/ -type l`; do 
    RES=`readlink -f $DISKLABEL`
    if [ $RES == $DEV ]; then
        LABEL="${DISKLABEL//*\//}"
    fi
done

FILE="/home/user/Remove_$LABEL"

echo '#!/bin/bash' > $FILE
echo "umount $DEV" >> $FILE
echo "udisks --detach $DEVR"  >> $FILE
echo "rm -fr $FILE" >> $FILE

chmod +x $FILE

exit
```

I've tested it on usb hard drives and flash dives as well.

Comment: Please report this issue (with workaround/fix) to the Fedora bugzilla. That way all Fedora users benefit.

Answer (score -1):

While I can't speak exactly for Gnome and Fedora, a simple and safe approach in a terminal window would be

```
# sudo umount /dev/sdaXXXX
```

where /dev/sdaXXXX represents whatever the usb drive is.  That information is easily obtained with just

```
# mount
```

When the umount command finishes, it is entirely safe to remove the USB drive from the computer.

Comment: Please read the question before answering.